# Как получить иконку учетной записи пользователя в след. ОС: Linux, OS X, Windows

Tags: javafx, c, java, objective-c, c++

Пишу приложение на базе JavaFX (JDK8). И столкнулся с проблемой: как получить иконку учетной записи в ОС (т.е. аватарку того пользователя, "под которым" было запущено приложение)?

P.S. Если есть кроссплатформенный способ (Linux, OS X, Windows), то это будет здорово. Если такого способа нет, то подойдут варианты с использованием C/C++ и/или Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроссплатформенного нет и быть не может. Под Linux можно поискать файл `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/юзернейм`, например, и распарсить его, там формат простой (ЕМНИП, если в `Icon=` файл без полного пути, то он в дефолтном каталоге `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/`).

Comment: Все так как вы сказали. Спасибо.
Что касается Win и OS X то ответы я нашел.